# Invisible TextNode in JS/DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have JS code like this:

```
    var option = document.createElement("input");
    option.id = "id";
    option.type = "radio";
    var txt = document.createTextNode("sample");
    option.appendChild(txt);
```

but this "sample" is invisible on the site. HTML structure is like this (in Firebug):

```
<form id="answers"><input type="radio" id="id">sample</input></form>
```

but in default firefox inspector is:

```
<form id="answers"><input type="radio" id="id"></input></form>
```

I've tried with innerHTML but there is the same problem. I just don't see anything between `<input>` tags.
What are your suggestions?

Comment: Input cannot contain any text (or any content), it becomes invalid so browser strips text content out of it. You may want to use label

Comment: input elements are void elements, i.e. they cannot have innerHTML or innerText/textContent. What do you want to achieve? Maybe it can be done using proper `<label>` element instead?

Comment: Oh, you're right of course. My oversight. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create the elements but do not append them to the form. You should use something like this:

```
document.getElementById('answers').appendChild(option);
```

In this way you will append the newly created option element to the form with id "answers".

**Have in mind that is is conceptually wrong to have text inside of a input type radio!**